# Why this Ember function after return is always undefined?

Tags: jquery, ember.js, ember-router

I have a route like this,

```
  App.NewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller,model) {
 var self=this;
        this.store.find('selectFill', { x: "20", y: "30" }).then(function (data) {
            var usersList=self.GetUsersList(data);    //usersList is always undefined even when GetUsersList returns the array.
            controller.set('users',usersList);
        });

    },
    GetUsersList: function (fillInfo) {
        fillInfo.forEach(function (item) {
            var users = item.get('users');
            var y = users.get('content').map(function (entity) {
                return entity.get('data');
            });
            return y;
        });
    }
});
```

Now the usersList is always undefined. i can see that GetUsersList does indded return an array, but usersList doesnt seems to take it.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not familiar with _Ember_ but it looks like it might be because you're using `self`, is `self` what you expect?

Comment: add __);__ atlast of the code

Comment: i posted only a fraction of the code for easy readability. i updated the snippet, it still doesnt work.

Comment: There is no `return` statement in `GetUsersList`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the return of the `GetUsersList` method from the question you have the following issues:

1. The `GetUsersList` should return something. You are wrongfully assuming that the `return` statement from inside the `forEach` is the return of the `GetUsersList` method
2. The result of the map should be concatenated somehow so your program doesn't have activity without any result

A possible right way to accomplish what you want would be like this:

```
GetUsersList: function (fillInfo) {
    // Array to hold all the data
    var returnVal = [];
    fillInfo.forEach(function (item) {
        // Inside forEach handler
        var users = item.get('users');
        var usersContentData = users.get('content').map(function (entity) {
             // Inside map handler
             return entity.get('data');
        });
        // No return here so the forEach doesn't interrupt and instead we append data to the returnVal array
        returnVal.push(usersContentData);
    });
    // Return the array that contains items pushed inside forEach handler
    return returnVal;
}
```

Comment: forEach doesn't stop executing when you return.

Answer (score 0):

```
App.NewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function (controller,model) {
 var self=this;
        this.store.find('selectFill', { x: "20", y: "30" }).then(function (data) {
            var usersList=self.GetUsersList(data);    //usersList is always undefined even when GetUsersList returns the array.
            controller.set('users',usersList);
        });

    },
    GetUsersList: function (fillInfo) {
var returnVal;
        fillInfo.forEach(function (item) {
            var users = item.get('users');
            var y = users.get('content').map(function (entity) {
                return entity.get('data');
            });
            returnVal=y;
        });
return returnVal;
    }
});
```

this did work. weird though, y was scoped inside the forEach loop, but why the function return undefined?

Comment: `forEach` isn't a loop, it is a function that invokes the anonymous callback function on each item in the `fillInfo` array.  You were returning from the callback, not `GetUsersList`